# Like button on React Native? I can't make it dynamically update

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

```
class PostButtons extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      liked: true,
    };
  }

  likeToggled() {
    this.setState({
      liked: !this.state.liked,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const heartIconColor = () => {
      if (this.state.liked === true) {
        return "red";
      } else if (this.state.liked === false) {
        return "black";
      }
    };



        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              this.likeToggled;
            }}
          >
            <Image
              style={{
                height: 37,
                width: 37,
                marginVertical: 395,
                marginHorizontal: 10,
                justifyContent: "flex-start",
                position: "absolute",
                tintColor: heartIconColor(),
              }}
              source={require("../Img/Heart3.png")}
            ></Image>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

I need it so when someone clicks the like button (initial state is black) it turns red then when they click it again it goes back to black. Currently i need to change this.state.liked to true and false to change the colours. I am not that advanced so an answer thats not verbose would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you weren't calling your likeToggled function. you were just accessing its definition which doesn't run the code inside your likeToggled function calling it like likeToggled() does

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.likeToggled();}} >
```